# Disabling the radio button or score increment after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

http://jsfiddle.net/nhZXg/36/

When the correct answer is clicked, me - John :), the score increments. Problem is that when you keep clicking John the score keeps incrementing.

I have done my research and found .unbind() jquery code but not sure how to implement it or if that even is the best solution.

What would people suggest.

Preferably I'd want the script to find the button that was clicked, instead of saying if(button1) was clicked, as an example, because this quiz may get quite big and that would be tedious.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Using this code now:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhZXg/38/

But it still will not function.

The page I am using this on is:
http://elearning.easy2dev.com/quiz_template_2.php

Any ideas why? I have included the jQuery 1.7.1 library too!

Done! :)

Comment: I see no jQuery in your example.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli's answer is great. I would just like to add that you might want to check out [jQuery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), so you can track which questions have been answered even if the user reloads the page.

Comment: thanks everyone. @j08691 there is no jquery in there, correct, I did say I didn't understand how to implement it.
@ Shankar, i will have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute any event handler only once then use jQuery `one` to bind the event handler. It will unbind itself once the event is triggered.

```
$('input:radio').one('click', function(){
     //do stuff here
});
```

You can change the logic in your code and try to make use of it but here is what you can try as per your code.

```
function scoreIncrement(elem) {//where elem is the radio button element that is clicked
    if(!$(elem).data('scored')){
       score++;
       document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
       $(elem).data('scored', true);
    }
}​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nhZXg/38/

Comment: My score increment stops working altogether now, any ideas? Shall I whack my code into jsFiddle?

Comment: No idea why mine is not working. I've put all the code in exactly, even the show/hide doesn't work now, I see it works in jsFiddle though. Could it be my jquery include as I can't see what jsFiddle is including:    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes, I do, I see "illegal character"
[Break On This Error]  

$(elem).data('scored', true);}​}

Comment: Update:

Removed all errors in the console now! Had to delete </script> and re-write it for some reason, weird. Now the quiz works, but the code you gave me isn't functioning like it is in jsfiddle. It just doesn't do anything! Any ideas?